# How to raise exception in a function working with a dataframe column - python

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I'm working with a dataframe with medicinal products and I have to extract the dosage out of the name (string), and later change the original product name with the reduced form of the dosage.

Example of what I have:

```
Name
'Prenoxad 2mg/2ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes'
```

I want to have, stored in a new column:

```
Name_reduced
'Prenoxad 1mg/ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes'
```

This is my code:

```
import re
from fractions import Fraction

def replace_ratio(ratio):
    fraction = Fraction(int(ratio.group(1)), int(ratio.group(2)))
    numerator = fraction.numerator
    denominator = "" if fraction.denominator == 1 else fraction.denominator
    return f"{numerator}ml/{denominator}mg"

def process_text(text):
    return re.sub(r"([\d\.]+)\s*mg\s*\/\s*([\d\.]+)\s*ml", lambda ratio: replace_ratio(ratio), text)

print(process_text("Prenoxad 2mg/2ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes")) 
# -> Prenoxad 1ml/mg solution for injection pre-filled syringes

print(process_text("Prenoxad 10mg/3ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes"))
# -> Prenoxad 10ml/3mg solution for injection pre-filled syringes

print(process_text("Prenoxad 120mg/6ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes"))
# -> Prenoxad 20ml/mg solution for injection pre-filled syringes
```

To use it in a dataframe column and store the outputs in another column I use:
`dftest['Name_reduced']=dftest['Name'].apply(process_text)`

It works well except when dealing with `floats`:

```
print(process_text("Imodium 10 mg/2.5 ml oral solution"))
#ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2.5'
```

To avoid this, I want the function to skip the products that have '.' as it only works with ints. Maybe something like:

```
if ("." in ratio.group(1)) or ("." in ratio.group(2)):
        pass
```

But I'm not sure how to do this, I don't know if raise exception would be the best approach.

Comment: Just use replace function : int(ratio.group(1).replace('.',',')) to get valid literal ;) Raise an exception for this seems a little bit extreme to me

Comment: That might not be ideal as it may result in something like `"Imodium 50mg/25 ml oral solution"` for some products, which would be transformed into: `"Imodium 2mg/ml oral solution"`. My approach will be to simply remove every product from the dataframe that has a '.', run the function for the remaining products and concatenate them in the end.